# Bitmap recycling Android

Tags: android, bitmap, garbage-collection

I'm trying to remove bitmaps from RAM. But when I use `System.gc()` it doesn't clean up RAM and application stops working with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` exception. Even when I use

```
if((bitmap!=null)&&(!bitmap.isRecycled())){
    bitmap.recycle();
    bitmap=null;
}
```

still no success.
It cleans up RAM, but I cant use recycled bitmaps again(**I load it again but can't use it for some strange reason**). 
Is there any proper way to clean bitmaps from RAM and use it later?

EDIT 0:

Loading bitmaps:

```
temp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bitmap);
bitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(temp, 100, 100, true);
```

Comment: Please explain **completely and precisely** what "I load it again but can't use it for some strange reason", including posting the relevant code and stack traces.

Comment: Trace is not quite interesting. In `logcat` I only get `Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when I use System.gc() it doesn't clean up RAM and application stops working with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError exception.

In part, that is because [you are fragmenting your heap](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/06/16/art-garbage-collection.html).

> It cleans up RAM, but I cant use recycled bitmaps again.

That is the point of `recycle()`.

> Is there any proper way to clean bitmaps from RAM and use it later?

Load the bitmaps in again. Please consider [using `inBitmap`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inBitmap) to *reuse* an existing `Bitmap` object, if the resolution is the same, rather than using `recycle()` and (pointlessly) calling `System.gc()`. Please also consider [using `inSampleSize`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) to reduce the memory usage of the bitmaps in the first place, by loading in something closer in resolution to what you intend to display.